# What is the difference between insertAdjacentHtml and insertAdjacentElement?

Tags: javascript

What is the main difference between element and html?
I used 
     
    `insertAdjacentElement('beforeend', html);`
   
and it showed error. But worked when using 
       
    `insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', html);`
  
Just wondering what the difference was.

Comment: The former inserts an existing DOM element, and the latter creates the elements to insert from the HTML _code_ that gets passed to it.

Comment: [MDN insertAdjacentHTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML) [MDN insertAdjacentElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentElement)

Comment: Your error probably occurred because `insertAdjacentElement` expects a reference to an existing HTML element, while `insertAdjacentHTML` can accept any valid HTML (or XML) markup. See the MDN articles ( Yury Tarabanko linked to them above) for details -- which is good advice for pretty much any web-development question :)

Comment: BTW, to make an "actual" element suitable for use with `insertAdjacentElement`, you can use the `createElement` method. For example, `const newDiv = document.createElement("div")`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

insertAdjacentElement() is used to insert an element which is already in the Dom.
You can get this element with getElementById() for example.
https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_node_insertadjacentelement.asp

insertAdjacentHtml() is used to insert html code.
https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_node_insertadjacenthtml.asp

Comment: The HTML element inserted with `insertAdjacentElement` may very likely be in the DOM already, but it's also possible for it to be a brandy-new element created in JavaScript, just sitting around awaiting its virgin insertion, so to speak.

Answer (score 0):

The insertAdjacentElement method is only compatible with either elements already present in the DOM or new elements created with document.createElement method.
The insertAdjacentHTML however will not work when you are trying to insert DOM elements into another but rather works on strings that can be parsed as XML or HTML which is then added to the parent container.

Although they are pretty similar in that they have more positioning parameters than node.appendchild and element.append methods